# PHP Proxy POST request to API with file upload

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, proxy

I have a job application form that contains a bunch of text inputs and two fields to upload files (resume and cover letter).

This form needs to post to a job board API endpoint but the request has to be proxied so the API key isn't seen in the post. This is working fine with just the text inputs but I can't figure out how to get the files to upload as well. Below is what I have so far, which only posts the text.

How do I need to go about uploading the files as well?

```
<?php

if ( $_POST ) {

    // API key
    $api_key = 'super_secret_key';

    $url = "https://api.myjobboard.io/applications/";
    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key . ":" . '' );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(  $_POST ) );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );

    echo $response;

} else {
    echo '<p>Error: No post data.</p>';
}

?>
```